# Android Emulator for windows?(Not to install the Complete SDK, Just Emulator Needed)

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any possible way to install Android Emulator itself on the windows. I would need that for the Testing purpose? Any Idea?

Please Note: I dont want to install whole sdk. i just want install the Emulater itself. that emulator is just like that a phone for the testing purpose.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'd like to do this myself.  Because I like to install my development environments on Virtual Boxes instead of on the main OS where they can be easily destroyed.  

Unfortunately my machine is not fast enough to run the android emulator on an emulated PC in the virtual box.  

This is why I would like the answer to this question as well.

Comment: Um..It doesn't work that way.  The SDK contains the AVD Manager which runs the emulators.  You can't get an emulator without the SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot download the emulator separately from the SDK, for any platform, for any version of Android.

Comment: Isnt' there a 3rd party solution?

Answer (score 2):

Modern update (mid-year 2013):

You can install Android inside a VirtualBox instance on your PC (Linux, Mac, Windows)

Steps:

1. Download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. Download the free & open source [Android OS ISO image](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list).
3. Install VirtualBox
4. Create new virtual machine with RAM, Hard Drive, etc.
5. Choose the Android ISO for CD-ROM drive
6. Start the virtual machine and follow on-screen instructions to install the OS.

Source:
http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

Comment: It looks worth trying. Trying it now. The link you have provided for ISO image, contains images only up to Android 4.x Do you know any other reliable source for downloading Android ISO Images?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is an option for a standalone Android Simulator, here it is:

http://www.redmondpie.com/android-emulator-for-windows/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a program called Jar of Beans created by a member of the XDA forum. 
http://code.google.com/p/jar-of-beans/

Its basically a Android Jelly Bean,

Hope it helps! its about 200MB in size.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question needs an update :) Here is an answer from 10/2018.

1. Bluestacks
2. MeMu
3. Genymotion
4. Andy
5. Droid4X
6. Nox
7. Windroy
8. AMIDuOS
9. Xamarin Android Player
10. Remix OS Player

Answer (score 0):

Well the [android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) contains an emulator and you can install it on Windows.

Comment: Make a note. I just want to install the emulator itself. Not whole SDK on the System.

Comment: If you open the SDK zip for windows, in the tools directory you have emulator.exe, but I have no clue if you can use it directly by extracting only this file without the rest of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run an emulator without its supporting avd and kernal. If you want to check you can try pasting the emultor.exe somewhere in your drive create a AVD and see if you are able to start the emulator from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Windroy](http://www.socketeq.com/), which is a free full port of Android to Windows.